# How to find a resource with key in code behind? [MAUI]

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, .net-maui

**How to find a resource with key in code behind?**

Also the equivalent to `{DynamicResource}`/`{StaticResource}` markup extensions.

In WPF the solution was:
`Style=(Style)FindResource("MyStyleKey");`
How to do this in MAUI?, because FindResource does not exist.

I don't feel like manually digging through all the merged dictionaries from Application.Resources

*I wonder why that no one has asked yet, have I overlooked the simple solution?*

**Edit1:**

LOL OK It hasn't crossed my mind to check if the ResourceDictionary searches itself recursively. But this is only the half work.
You still have to traverse the current element tree backwards.

Therefore, the question is still reasonable why FindResource is not implemented by default? or whether there is already a function somewhere else that does exactly that?

**Edit2:**

I brought the question to the more important point, How to find a resource, not how to assign.
The original question was "How to assign a Style with key in code behind"

Comment: how about ```Style = Application.Resources["MyStyleKey"] as Style```

Comment: @Shaw That assumes it is in Application.Resources. But I don't know where it is, so the question is HOW TO FIND it, not how to assign it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long there is no default, here is my substitute.

```
public static class ResourceHelper{

    public static object FindResource(this VisualElement o, string key) {
        while (o != null) {
            if (o.Resources.TryGetValue(key, out var r1)) return r1;
            if (o is Page) break;
            if (o is IElement e) o = e.Parent as VisualElement;
        }
        if (Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue(key, out var r2)) return r2;
        return null;
    }
}
```

> *It is not enough that a function works, it must work perfectly.*

Since I lack of deep framework insights, I am of course not sure if the logic is perfect. So any correction is welcome.

Comment: I dont know how to use in [my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72977744/the-resource-is-not-present-in-the-dictionary)

Answer (score 7):

```
    AppTheme currentTheme = Application.Current.RequestedTheme;
// The First Dictionary merged in App.xaml is the Colors Dictionary
var rd = App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.First();
if(currentTheme== AppTheme.Dark)
{
    
    _barColor = (Color)rd["Secondary"];
    _borderColor = (Color)rd["Gray600"];
    _TrackColor = (Color)rd["Tertiary"];
}
else
{
    _barColor = (Color)rd["Primary"];
    _borderColor = (Color)rd["Gray950"];
    _TrackColor = (Color)rd["Secondary"];
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But when the colors are overwritten locally, the overwritten values are not used.

Answer (score 7):

One Simple Way is to create a custom static dictionary to access merged dictionaries in App.xaml.cs

Here in my case, It will be *Colors.xaml* as *Resource dictionary*.
And path is *Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml;assembly=SampleApp*

In this dictionary, *Colors* as key and *ResourceDictionary* as Value

In App.xaml

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

In App.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class App : Application 
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new AppShell();
        ResourceDictionary = new Dictionary<string, ResourceDictionary>();
        foreach (var dictionary in Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries)
        {
            string key = dictionary.Source.OriginalString.Split(';').First().Split('/').Last().Split('.').First(); // Alternatively If you are good in Regex you can use that as well
            ResourceDictionary.Add(key, dictionary);
        }
    }

    public static Dictionary<string,ResourceDictionary> ResourceDictionary;
}
```

Consuming dictionary in C# code

```cs
(Color)App.ResourceDictionary["Colors"]["ColorKey"]
```

Comment: Thx. Unfortunately this does not answer the question in WHICH ResourceDictionary you can find the resource.

Comment: I edited with the use case. Hope this answers your question

Comment: I mean this ist not an answer to my question. I don't want to create resources, I want' to find existing one! The question is already answered. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72610077/2369575

Answer (score 0):

Asuming that the style alreay has a `x:key` property named `MyStyleKey`

If the Style  in `App.xaml`

```
Style style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["MyStyleKey"];
```

If the Style  in `Page.xaml`

```
Style style = (Style)Resources["MyStyleKey"];
```

Comment: the Style could be elsewhere in the visual tree, so this is only a partial solutions, but thanks, it points me into right direction to implement FindResource (if there is no such function already)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/73667609/3495516
Its strange you cannot access is from code, but from xaml you can

Comment: what does this have to do with my question?

Comment: best answer. for some reason `(Style)Application.Current.Resources["StyleKey"]` isnt finding a style that `{x:StaticResource StyleKey}` finds so this solved my issue. hope they fix this or someone explains why we arent able to use the simple c# way. now, kux why you have your resource dictionaries "somewhere" if its to use globally just define it globally

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach?

```
internal static class ApplicationExtensions
{
    internal static Style GetStyle<T>(this Application app) where T : VisualElement
    {
        var styles = app.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Last();
        return (Style)styles[typeof(T).FullName];
    }

    internal static bool TryGetStyle<T>(this Application app, out Style? style) where T : VisualElement
    {
        var styles = app.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Last();
        var success = styles.TryGetValue(typeof(T).FullName, out object value);
        style = success ? (Style)value : null;
        return success;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// get the style of a Label in an unsafe way
var labelStyle = Application.Current!.GetStyle<Label>();

// get the style of an Entry in a safe way
if (Application.Current!.TryGetStyle<Entry>(out var style)) 
{
    // do something with the style ...
}
```

There's 2 methods to retrieve a style. An unsafe method that could crash if the style doesn't exist. Would be safe to use if you are always sure what the App Resources contain. There's a second safe approach, but it requires a bit more code to use (similar to other `Try*` methods in the C# frameworks.

***PLEASE NOTE (1)**: I get the style from the last merged dictionary. The first merged dictionary contains the colors. The extension could be extended to also return color info from the first merged dictionary with similar code.*

***PLEASE NOTE (2)**: The assumption here is that styles are always applied to subclasses of `VisualElement`. I am not sure this would always be correct, but otherwise the restriction could be loosened.*