# The resource is not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, maui

I'm trying to get a StaticResource at code behind but when I debug just get a empty response.
In my `MainPage.xaml.cs` I have:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    /*Create buttons*/
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        FlexGrid.Add(BtnAdd(i + 1));
    }
}

private Button BtnAdd(int btnNum)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Text = "TestButton " + btnNum;
    btn.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
    btn.WidthRequest = 125;
    btn.HeightRequest = 125;
    //Here i get empty response 
    btn.BorderColor = Resources["Secondary"] as Color;
    btn.BorderWidth = 5;
    btn.Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5);
    btn.Clicked += TestBTN;

    return btn;
}
```

When debug says:

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The resource 'Secondary' is not present in the dictionary

[image: EmptyDebug]

The element is in the folder Resources/Styles/colors.xaml and is a `ResourceDictionary` in front i can take it just with `{StaticResource Secondary}`.

How can I get it at code behind?

**EDIT**

I find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72591153/how-to-find-a-resource-with-key-in-code-behind-maui) and I try the answers, the static class answer I don't know why I need a VisualElement and the others give me this:

```
var rd = App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.First();
```

[image]

So now I take the Resource dictionary but with null response of each element.

Comment: Typo? Secundary vs Secondary?

Comment: Correct: btn.BorderColor = Resources["Secondary"] as Color;

Comment: sorry writing mistake, but the problem continues

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the problem is that resources are global not local(page) so `Page.Resources` doesn't contains this ... in WPF we use `Application.Current.FindResource` to get global resources. I don't know how to get them in MAUI as there is no class references(or I could not find them)

Comment: If its global, should be found by `Application.Current.Resources["yourkeyhere"]`.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Using that i get an exception `The resource 'Secondary' is not present in the dictionary`, the most acurance is what I put in the edit

Comment: Please open it as an issue at [github maui issues](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues). And in that issue, link back to this question.  Logically, those colors should be merged into the global resources. If that isn't what they intend to do, then I agree, we need `Application.Current.FindResource` for Maui.

Answer (score 2):

a workaround is to make a local Resource which has a BasedOn property on the global style

```xml
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="button_icons_style_LOCAL" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{x:StaticResource button_icons_style}"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

and then to use the local one in the code.

```cs
new Button() { Style = (Style)Resources["button_icons_style_LOCAL"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, I couldn't find a 'native' Maui solution. So I written my own recursive helper:

```
public static class ResourcesHelper
{
    public static bool TryGetResource<T>(this Application application, string key, out T foundItem)
    {
        foundItem = default;
        if (application is null) return false;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key)) return false;
        // Find first matching resource of type T
        var found = TraverseDictionary(application.Resources, key).FirstOrDefault(pair => pair.Value is T);
        if (found.Key == null) return false;
        foundItem = (T)found.Value;
        return true;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> TraverseDictionary(ResourceDictionary dictionary, string key)
    {
        if (dictionary is null) yield break;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var item))
            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(key, item);
        foreach (var nextDictionary in dictionary.MergedDictionaries)
        {
            foreach (var nextPair in TraverseDictionary(nextDictionary, key))
                yield return nextPair;
        }
    }
}
```